# Extracting geo coordinates from a complex nested Twitter json, using Python

Tags: python, json, geolocation, coordinates

I am reading multiple complex json files and trying to extract geo coordinates.
I cannot attach the file itself right now, but I can print the tree here.
The file has several hundred options and some objects repeat.

Please see the structure of the file in [`.txt` format](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A8Hm441gP8Yy4rqll1gCFc3s1GyrxMsb/view?usp=sharing).

When I read the json with Spark in Python, it shows me these coordinates in `coordinates` column and it is there.

It is stored in `coordinates` column. Please see a proof.

[image]

I am obviously trying to reduce the number of columns and select some columns.

The last two columns are my geo coordinates. I tried both `coordinates` and `geo` and also `coordinates.coordinates` with `geo.coordinates`. Both options do not work.

```
df_tweets = tweets.select(['text', 
                       'user.name', 
                       'user.screen_name', 
                       'user.id', 
                       'user.location',  
                       'place.country', 
                       'place.full_name', 
                       'place.name',
                       'user.followers_count', 
                       'retweet_count',
                       'retweeted',
                       'user.friends_count',
                       'entities.hashtags.text', 
                       'created_at', 
                       'timestamp_ms', 
                       'lang',
                       'coordinates.coordinates', # or just `coordinates`
                       'geo.coordinates' # or just `geo`
                       ])
```

In the first case with `coordinates` and `geo` I get the following, printing the schema:

```
df_tweets.printSchema()

root
 |-- text: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- screen_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- location: string (nullable = true)
 |-- country: string (nullable = true)
 |-- full_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- followers_count: long (nullable = true)
 |-- retweet_count: long (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- friends_count: long (nullable = true)
 |-- text: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- created_at: string (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp_ms: string (nullable = true)
 |-- lang: string (nullable = true)
 |-- coordinates: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- coordinates: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- geo: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- coordinates: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
```

When I do `coordinates.coordinates` and `geo.coordinates`, I get

```
root
 |-- text: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- screen_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- location: string (nullable = true)
 |-- country: string (nullable = true)
 |-- full_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- followers_count: long (nullable = true)
 |-- retweet_count: long (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- friends_count: long (nullable = true)
 |-- text: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- created_at: string (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp_ms: string (nullable = true)
 |-- lang: string (nullable = true)
 |-- coordinates: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
 |-- coordinates: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
```

When I print both dataframes in Pandas, none of them gives me coordinates, I still have `None`.

How to extract geo coordinates properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I look at my dataframe with tweet data, I see it like this

```
In [44]: df[df.coordinates.notnull()]['coordinates']
Out[44]:
98    {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [-122.32111, ...
99    {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [-122.32111, ...
Name: coordinates, dtype: object
```

So it's a dictionary that has to be parsed

```
tweets_coords = df[df.coordinates.notnull()]['coordinates'].tolist()

for coords in tweets_coords:
    print(coords)
    print(coords['coordinates'])
    print(coords['coordinates'][0])
    print(coords['coordinates'][1])
```

Output:

```
{'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [-122.32111, 47.62366]}
[-122.32111, 47.62366]
-122.32111
47.62362
{'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [-122.32111, 47.62362]}
[-122.32111, 47.62362]
-122.32111
47.62362
```

You can setup a lambda function in `apply()` to parse these out row by row, otherwise you can use list comprehension using what i've provided as the basis for your analysis.

All that said, maybe check this first...
Where you are using `coordinates.coordinates` and `geo.coordinates`, try `coordinates['coordinates']` and `geo['coordinates']`

Comment: Thanks for spending your time! I probably can access, using your code, but I can access all other variables, using `select`. Any idea how to do it with `select`?

Comment: Can you edit your question and add code that shows the select usage? I’m not sure what you are doing so can’t answer without more info.

Comment: My select code is already there! I added it above the structure of json.

Comment: from the end of my answer, look at this: All that said, maybe check this first... Where you are using coordinates.coordinates and geo.coordinates, try coordinates['coordinates'] and geo['coordinates']. It's hard to debug without the actual data you are using.